# How to select specific link and make it die

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make a carrier collect sheet metal from delivery and drop it off at the cutter. The cutter will cut the metal sheet into one of the two bodies and will output it to be collected by a carrier. Is creating and destroying links such as below the best approach to simulating the carriers carrying, dropping off and collecting the items? If so, how do I select the specific link to die? I've marked where NetLogo expected 2 inputs with "X X" as I am unsure what to write there. Cheers

```
globals[
  metal-sheets
  cutter-closest-free-carrier
  s-welder-closest-free-carrier
  p-welder-closest-free-carrier
  skeletons
  standard-skeletons
]

breed[carriers carrier]
breed[cars car]

cars-own [
body; standard, prestige
]
```

```
to cut
  let free-carriers carriers with [laden = false]   
  let cutter patches with [machine-type = "cutter"] 
  let delivery patches with [area = "delivery"]
  set cutter-closest-free-carrier nobody

  ask cutter [
  if status = "import" [
      set cutter-closest-free-carrier min-one-of free-carriers[distance myself]]   ]

  if cutter-closest-free-carrier != nobody[
      ask cutter-closest-free-carrier [
      set target delivery
      face one-of delivery 
      fd 0.01
      set metal-sheets cars-here
      if any? metal-sheets [
        create-link-to one-of metal-sheets [tie]
        set laden true
        set target cutter
        face one-of cutter
        fd 0.01
        ask cutter[
           set metal-sheets cars-here
      if any? metal-sheets [
            ask link  X X [die]
          set status "pending"
          create-link-to one-of metal-sheets [tie]]       
        ] 
      ]    
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to answer your question because I think you have got yourself in a real tangle with timing here. The whole thing needs to be reorganised, which will end up with a completely different question.

This code has the cutter finding a sheet, delivering it etc all within one procedure. The implication is that this all happens in the same tick. However, it is only moving forward 0.1. You need to think about the process in an entirely different way.

What happens during one time step? Some cutters find and cut a sheet. Other cutters that already have a sheet move toward the delivery point. Other cutters deliver their sheet. These all need to be different procedures. The cutters delivering their sheet are the ones where the link dies, but you won't have to identify them (what you have as X X) because only cutters doing deliveries will be implementing the procedure.

Have a look at the `go` procedure in the NetLog0 Models Library model called Shepherds. That has a similar structure to what you need here.